# Как передать значение переменной js в другую функцию

Tags: javascript, ajax, функции, переменные

Имеется таблица, меняю значения, и для того чтобы передать изменения на сервер нужно нажать кнопку, собственно не получается передать значение переменной ids

отсюда

```
$(function()    {
    $('td').dblclick(function(editelement)  {
        var tags = editelement.target || editelement.srcElement;
        var elm_name = tags.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if(elm_name == 'input') {return false;}
        var val = $(this).html(); 
        var code = '<input type="text" id="edit" value="'+val+'" />'; 
        $(this).empty().append(code); 
        $('#edit').focus(); 
        $('#edit').blur(function()  { 
            var val = $(this).val(); 
            $(this).parent().empty().html(val);
        });
        var ids = $(this).parent('tr').attr('id');
    });
});
```

вот в эту функцию

```
function submitForm(){


                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'partnersedit.php',
                data:'ids='+ ids;
            });
            };
```

или как сохранить значение этой переменной пока не будет нажата кнопка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="ids" />


$("#ids").val($(this).parent('tr').attr('id'));


function submitForm(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'partnersedit.php',
    data:'ids='+ $("#ids").val();
  });
});
```

*Совет дня:*

Не забывайте "принимать" (знак "галочка" слева от ответа) ответы на Ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Ну самым разумным способом будет объявить переменную до первой функции, а потом просто в параметрах второй функции передать саму переменную, при этом в первой функции заполнить значением переменную. Вам нужно изучать замыкание.

Пример.

```
var value = null;
function test()
{
    value = 12;
}

function testTwo(param) 
{
    console.log(param);
}

test();
testTwo(value);//12
```

Comment: где здесь "замыкание"?

Comment: @Igor, его надо изучить. Я не говорил что показываю пример замыкания. :)

Comment: Хорошо, только странно, что Вы хотите, чтобы ТС изучал именно замыкания. А все остальное?

Comment: Ну если бы человек изучил замыкание и области видимости переменных в JavaScript, то вероятннн всего, он бы не задал этот вопрос. Но а так-то да, ученик свет, учить надо все, не спорю же.